# is hadoop necessary for using Giraph

Tags: hadoop, graph, giraph

I want to use Giraph as a graph processing tool for my work. I am familiar with Mahout and I know I can use some parts of Mahout such as Recommender System without using Hadoop. However, I don't know if this is the same for Giraph and whether I can use it without using Hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Hadoop in order to run Giraph as the single tasks (master and worker) are internally executed as map-only jobs. Alternatively, you can also run Giraph as a yarn application.

Have a look at the [giraph quick start guide](http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html) and search the [mailing list](http://giraph.apache.org/mail-lists.html) if you get into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Hadoop dependency, but you do not need a Hadoop cluster, not even a pseudo-distributed one. Chapter 5 of the book [Practical Graph Analytics with Apache Giraph](http://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484212523) shows an example for this - the source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/apress/practical-graph-analytics-w-apache-giraph).

The following dependencies are required:

- org.apache.giraph:giraph-core:1.1.0
- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1

Implement your computation as a subclass of `BasicComputation` an run it [as follows](https://github.com/Apress/practical-graph-analytics-w-apache-giraph/blob/master/giraph-book-giraph-book/05.Chapter%2005%20(Working%20with%20Giraph)/src/test/java/TestGiraphApp.java):

```
String[] graphSeed = new String[] { "seed\t0" }

GiraphConfiguration conf = new GiraphConfiguration();
conf.setComputationClass(GenerateTwitterParallel.class);
conf.setVertexInputFormatClass(
    TextDoubleDoubleAdjacencyListVertexInputFormat.class);
conf.setVertexOutputFormatClass(
    AdjacencyListTextVertexOutputFormat.class);
Iterable<String> results =
    InternalVertexRunner.run(conf, graphSeed);
```